# Preceding sibling return empty node

Tags: xpath

In this example i have this code:

```
<table class="basicinfo" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="header">
    <td colspan="3">
      <div>
        <h2 class="prod_card">Basic info</h2>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row2 item">
    <td class="cell0">
      <div>
        Year
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="cell1">
      <div>
        2005
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row3 item alt">
    <td class="cell0">
      <div>
        Extra
      </div>
    </td>

    <td class="cell1">
      <div>
        -
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, i want to get (for example) the `year`. I'm trying to get the next `div` content after the `div` with `Year` content.

I'm using this xpath without success:

```
//div[preceding-sibling::div = 'Year']
```

And anyone knows a good website to start learning xpath? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following XPath

```
//div[parent::td/preceding-sibling::td//div[normalize-space()= 'Year']]
```

has the result

```
<div>2005</div>
```

Your XPath didn't work because the `div` you are looking for has not a `div` element as  `preceding-sibling` but a `td` as `parent`. The `preceding-sibling::td` of this `td` contains a div which has the text "Year" - `td//div`. Using `normalize-space()` returns the text of this `div` without any spaces which can be necessary when checking for equality.

For reference: [normalize-space()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and as you asked for good resources - I don't want to recommend anything special, but you should have a look at the resources mentioned at the info given on stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath/info (if not already done) and, for XPath axes, this is a good visualization: http://www.xmlplease.com/axis